# class.phpmailer is getting error while we sent mail in php

Tags: php, email

when i try to sent mail via class.phpmailer it is showing following error.

[image]

> Fatal error: Class 'SMTP' not found in D:\InetPub\vhosts\aaaaaaaa.com\httpdocs\class.phpmailer.php on line 1520

the host gator Control panel

[image]

my code is as follows

```
<?php 

 require_once('class.phpmailer.php');

    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->CharSet =  "utf-8";
    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = "user@gmail.com";
    $mail->Password = "password";
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";  
    $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    $mail->Port = "465";

    $mail->setFrom('fromuser@gmail.com', 'AAAA');
    $mail->AddAddress('touser@mail.com', 'BBBB');

    $mail->Subject  =  'using PHPMailer';
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->Body    = 'Hi there ,
                        <br />
                        this mail was sent using PHPMailer...
                        <br />
                        cheers... :)';

     if($mail->Send())
     {
        echo "Message was Successfully Send :)";
     }
     else
     {
        echo "Mail Error - >".$mail->ErrorInfo;
     }

?>
```

am using host gator control pannel

Comment: Can you share where `class.phpmailer.php` file is placed? share complete path

Comment: in the httpdocs in the host gator control panel

Comment: try to `require_once` with complete path.

Comment: y downvote .... ??

Comment: means?? i didnot understand

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145298/discussion-between-sahil-gulati-and-dona-susan-issac).

Comment: If you use namespaces, you may have to put \SMTP (or whatever it is)

Comment: @NigelRen means show sample